# Spark scala - add a json column from other columns conditionally

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

With a dataframe such as :

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|old_a|new_a|    a|old_b|new_b|    b|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|    6|    7| true|    6|    6|false|
|    1|    1|false|   12|    8| true|
|    1|    2| true|    2|    8| true|
|    1| null| true|    2|    8| true|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

note : 'a' is 'true' when 'new_a' is different from 'old_a', the same for 'b'

I'd like to add a json column, with some values from other columns, following that rule
"if 'a' is true, value of 'new_a' col must be added to the new json, and the same for 'b'",

which will produce following dataframe

```
+-----+-----+--------+-----+-----+--------+------------------------+
|old_a|new_a|a       |old_b|new_b|       b| json                   |
+-----+-----+--------+-----+-----+--------+------------------------+
|    6|    7|    true|    6|    6|   false| { "a" : 7 }            |
|    1|    1|   false|   12|    8|    true| { "b" : 8 }            |    
|    1|    2|    true|    2|    8|    true| { "a" : 2, "b" : 8}    |
|    1| null|    true|    2|    8|    true| { "a" : null, "b" : 8} |
+-----+-----+--------+-----+-----+--------+------------------------+
```

Is there a way to achieve that without UDFs ?

If not what would best way to write the UDF so it won't be too costly ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `to_json` & `struct` functions.

By default `to_json` function removes all `null` value columns, due to this reason I have converted `new_a` column datatype to `string`

`new_a` datatype `integer`

```
scala> df.show(false)
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|old_a|new_a|a    |old_b|new_b|b    |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|6    |7    |true |6    |6    |false|
|1    |1    |false|12   |8    |true |
|1    |2    |true |2    |8    |true |
|1    |null |true |2    |8    |true |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+


scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- old_a: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- new_a: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- a: boolean (nullable = false)
 |-- old_b: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- new_b: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- b: boolean (nullable = false)


scala> df.withColumn("json",when($"a" && $"b",to_json(struct($"new_a",$"new_b"))).when($"a",to_json(struct($"new_a"))).otherwise(to_json(struct($"new_b")))).show(false)
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+---------------------+
|old_a|new_a|a    |old_b|new_b|b    |json                 |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+---------------------+
|6    |7    |true |6    |6    |false|{"new_a":7}          |
|1    |1    |false|12   |8    |true |{"new_b":8}          |
|1    |2    |true |2    |8    |true |{"new_a":2,"new_b":8}|
|1    |null |true |2    |8    |true |{"new_b":8}          |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+---------------------+
```

`new_a` datatype `string`

```
scala> df.show(false)
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|old_a|new_a|a    |old_b|new_b|b    |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|6    |7    |true |6    |6    |false|
|1    |1    |false|12   |8    |true |
|1    |2    |true |2    |8    |true |
|1    |null |true |2    |8    |true |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+


scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- old_a: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- new_a: string (nullable = true)
 |-- a: boolean (nullable = false)
 |-- old_b: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- new_b: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- b: boolean (nullable = false)


scala> df.withColumn("json",when($"a" && $"b",to_json(struct($"new_a",$"new_b"))).when($"a",to_json(struct($"new_a"))).otherwise(to_json(struct($"new_b")))).show(false)
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+--------------------------+
|old_a|new_a|a    |old_b|new_b|b    |json                      |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+--------------------------+
|6    |7    |true |6    |6    |false|{"new_a":"7"}             |
|1    |1    |false|12   |8    |true |{"new_b":8}               |
|1    |2    |true |2    |8    |true |{"new_a":"2","new_b":8}   |
|1    |null |true |2    |8    |true |{"new_a":"null","new_b":8}|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+--------------------------+
```

Comment: yes, thanks again. But I forgot to say that I don't know in advance the number of columns. We can have lot of "old_X / new_X / X". But I may tweak your solution by starting from a seq of column names, and using folding try to build dynamically the to_json column. Would you know how to to that starting from that example ? May be I'll have to build a column of type Struc/Map, and then convert to json

Comment: ok, let me know if its not working ..also Please upvote & accept this answer if it helps to solve issue.. :)

Comment: do you have any specific pattern to identify new & old columns ?

Comment: I don't know in advance how much column I'll have, I just know the pattern will be old_X / new_X , X.

Comment: do you have columns always like this a, new_a, old_a in this pattern a is actual column ?

Comment: I created the 'a' column by comparing the "old_a"/"new_a", true if it changed, false else. I did it by using a foldLeft on seq of column names I manipulated.

Comment: yes the pattern is always the same with a the actual column

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213914/discussion-between-philippe-and-srinivas).

Answer (score 0):

A solution to generalize Srinivas solution, when we don't know the number of      old/new column pairs

(note something I didn't mention is that col 'a' and 'b' where here to tell if the value changed between old a and new a (respectively b)

```
   val df = Seq(
      (null, "a", "b", "b"),
      ("a", null, "b", "b"),
      ("a", "a2", "b", "b"),
      ("a", "a2", "b", "b2"),
      (null, null, "b", "b2"),
    ).toDF("old_a", "new_a","old_b", "new_b")

    // replace null by empty string to not mess with the voluntary null value we set later
    val df2 = df.na.fill("",df.columns)

    df2.show()

    val colNames = df2.columns.map(name => name.stripPrefix("old_").stripPrefix("new_")).distinct
    val res = colNames.foldLeft(df2){(tempDF, colName) =>
      tempDF.withColumn(colName,
        when(col(s"old_$colName").equalTo(col(s"new_$colName")), null)
        .otherwise(col(s"new_$colName"))
      )
    }
    val cols: Array[Column] = colNames.map(col(_))
    val resWithJson = res.withColumn("json", to_json(struct(cols:_*)))
```

output :

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|old_a|new_a|old_b|new_b|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |    a|    b|    b|
|    a|     |    b|    b|
|    a|   a2|    b|    b|
|    a|   a2|    b|   b2|
|     |     |    b|   b2|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+

+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+----+-------------------+
|old_a|new_a|old_b|new_b|a   |b   |json               |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+----+-------------------+
|     |a    |b    |b    |a   |null|{"a":"a"}          |
|a    |     |b    |b    |    |null|{"a":""}           |
|a    |a2   |b    |b    |a2  |null|{"a":"a2"}         |
|a    |a2   |b    |b2   |a2  |b2  |{"a":"a2","b":"b2"}|
|     |     |b    |b2   |null|b2  |{"b":"b2"}         |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+----+-------------------+
```